# Which registry key corresponds to the “Network Security: Restrict NTLM: Incoming NTLM Traffic” group policy?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, group-policy

Which registry key corresponds to the “Network Security: Restrict NTLM: Incoming NTLM Traffic” group policy?  I am interested in Windows 10 specifically, but I also would like to know about Windows 8.1 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the Windows 10 realm, it can be found in the following location:

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0\RestrictReceivingNTLMTraffic

(Source: [Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250))

The group policy reference spreadsheet emphasizes that those settings are `Supported on: At least Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2`, and I confirmed that the same registry key was specified on older versions of that document aimed at Windows 8.1 as well as Windows 7.